# find the Expected Value: (1/n^2)E[(ln(x1)+...+ln(xn))^2]

Tags: statistics

I need to find the Expected Value: (1/n2 )E[(ln(x1)+...+ln(xn))2 ] and the only information I get is that E[ln(xi)] = a, E[ln(xi)2 ] = 2a2 where i = 1,2,...,n.

The problem I'm having is with the whole thing being raised to the second power, I don't know how to break the EV down into manageable chunks. If it wasn't in the second power it would just be...

(1/n2 )E[(ln(x1)+...+ln(xn))] = (1/n2 )(E[ln(x1)] + ... + E[ln(xn)]) = (1/n2 )(na) = a/n

...right?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(X_i)\right)^2 \right) & = \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \ln^2(X_i) + \sum_{i\neq j}\ln(X_i)\ln(X_j)\right)\right)\\
& = n \mathbb{E}\left(\ln^2(X)\right) + n(n-1) \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\ln(X)\right) \right)^2
\end{align}

Comment: You might need $n(n-1)$ instead of  $n^2$ on the right.